# How to iterate an object of arrays in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach

I am trying to auto-populate the city based on zip code value. So far I have been able to match the user input zip code with a static list of zip code but I am facing trouble implementing the logic to fetch the cities corresponding to the zip code entered by the user.

Below is a snippet of the ts and html file from my app

### test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

profileForm = this.fb.group({
organizationAddress: this.fb.group({
      street:['', Validators.required],
      zip: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      state:['', Validators.required]
    })
});

zip = {
  "city1": ["1", "2" ],
  "city2":[ "3", "4", "5"],
  "city3":[ "6", "7" ]
};


onKeyUp(event: any){

  let city, zipCodes = this.zip, score;

  for (let i=0; i<Object.keys(zipCodes).length; i++ ){
    Object.values(zipCodes).forEach(function (value){
      for( let zip in value){
        if(event.target.value == `${value[zip]}`){
          
          score = `${value[zip]}`;
          break;
        } 
      }
      if(score = Object.values(zipCodes))
      {
        console.log("city ",Object.keys(score))
        city = Object.keys(score);
      }
    })
  }
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      organizationAddress:{
      city: city}
    })
  }
```

### test.component.html

```
<div formGroupName="organizationAddress">
      <h4>Address</h4>
      <label for="zip">Zip Code  : </label>
      <input id="zip" type="text" formControlName="zip" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"><br/>
      <label for="city">City  : </label>
      <input id="city" type="text" formControlName="city"><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple function that returns the correct city for a given zip code:

```js
zipCodes = {
  "city1": ["1", "2" ],
  "city2":[ "3", "4", "5"],
  "city3":[ "6", "7" ]
};


getCity = theCurrentZip => {
  return Object.keys(zipCodes).filter(z => {
    return zipCodes[z].includes(theCurrentZip)
  })[0]
}

console.log(getCity("7"))
console.log(getCity("2"))
console.log(getCity("99"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution.
Just a small update for typescript syntax -
`code`
   zipCodes: any = {
     "city1": ["1", "2" ],
     "city2":[ "3", "4", "5"],
     "city3":[ "6", "7" ]
   };

   getCity = (theCurrentZip: any) => {
     return Object.keys(this. zipCodes).filter(z => {
       return this. zipCodes[z].includes(theCurrentZip)
     })[0]
   }
`code`